# Where does Xcode 4 hide the preferences plist file of an app in deveopment

Tags: xcode, cocoa, plist, osx-mountain-lion

I'm building an OSX app and am currently putting together the preferences pane. I need to verify that some of the user defaults are being created properly, but I keep being shown changes to the preferences that I have done through the app during a "build and run". In previous versions this plist file would be at ~/Library/Preferences/[bundle identifier].plist, but in this case, no such file exists, yet changes to the preferences are most definitely persisting between launches, so they have to be getting stored somewhere.

Comment: At least with the test program I just made, they're still there.

Comment: Not with the one I'm working on. Checked /Library/Preferences, ~/Library/Preferences in both Finder and in Terminal, searching for hidden files as well. I should also not I am on Mountain Lion if that makes any difference. If things aren't staying in a plist anymore, I need to find where they are being stored.

Comment: I am on Mountain Lion, and I can assure you that the plist file for my app is there. Try `defaults read [bundle identifier]` in the terminal to see if you get anything; if not, I suggest that you double-check your bundle identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a sandboxed app your files will be in ~/Library/Containers/[bundle identifier]